# How to get the data in decline pattern/trending using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How can I get the result only for those monthly data in decline pattern/trending ?

And the data as below;

```
ID   JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN 
112  50  45  40  35  30  20
113  30  30  30  30  30  30
114  20  25  20  20  20  20
115  45  50  60  60  30  30
```

Expected output ;

```
ID   JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN 
112  50  45  40  35  30  20
115  45  50  60  60  30  30
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is your expected o/p if ID 115 all data are 10  ?

Comment: expected result : any trending are decrease compared to previous month.

Comment: @kfm Shouldn't 114 be counted then, since MAR is less than FEB?

Comment: "any **trending** are decrease compared to..." - what do you mean by that? I am sure that makes no sense in your native language either, not just in English.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  JAN > JUN
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  JAN > FEB
AND    FEB > MAR
AND    MAR > APR
AND    APR > MAY
AND    MAY > JUN
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you're looking for is

```
SELECT *
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE JAN > FEB OR
        FEB > MAR OR
        MAR > APR OR
        APR > MAY OR
        MAY > JUN
```

Best of luck.